# How to capture application monitoring information from the docker container

Tags: docker, jvm, openjdk-11, jstack, jstat

I have more than one java application running in separate docker containers. I am trying to collect monitoring data such as GC log, thread dump, heap dump from the java process running inside a container using tools like jstat, jstack, jmap. Is it possible to capture this information from the host(outside containers)?

I am new to the containerized world. I understand that PID namespace of the host and container is different. When I execute `jstack <PID> > thread_dump.txt` from the host, it shows error message: **Unable to open socket file /proc/root/tmp/.java_pid: target process  doesn't respond within 10500ms or HotSpot VM not loaded**

> Where PID is process id from the host PID namespace.

When I execute `jstack` inside container ( `docker exec -it <container_id_or_name>`) then it is able to capture thread dump.

> Where PID is process id from the container PID namespace.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) tool serves exactly for this purpose. The project is free and open source.

Examples:

- `jattach <pid> threaddump` (works like jstack)
- `jattach <pid> inspectheap` (works like jmap -histo)
- `jattach <pid> jcmd GC.class_stats`

where `<pid>` is Java process ID in the host namespace.

As a bonus, `jattach` works even if container runs JRE with no JDK tools (jstack, jcmd, etc.) installed.

Comment: Hi @apangin, Super! I tried to install ```jattach``` package on centos7 but it seems the package is not available. Kindly advise.

Comment: @Mahesh Download the [provided binary](https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases/tag/v2.0) or build it yourself (it's just a single `make` command).

Comment: Thank you :) Let me try.

Comment: I executed the ```make``` command from the directory where the ```makefile``` is present. I got the following error: 
```mkdir -p build
cc  -O3  -DJATTACH_VERSION=\"2.0\" -o build/jattach src/posix/*.c
/bin/sh: cc: command not found
make: *** [build/jattach] Error 127```

Comment: I have installed ```gcc``` package as mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095168/command-not-found-cc-make-error-127. Now when I execute ```make``` command it shows message "make: Nothing to be done for `all'."

Comment: Just download prebuilt binary on the [Releases](https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases/tag/v2.0) page.

Comment: I am getting a "Failed to change credentials to match the target process: Operation not permitted" error when I executed the ```jattach <PID> threaddump``` command. Any idea?

Comment: @Mahesh To attach to Java processes running under different users, you need to start jattach under a privileged user (root). Try `sudo jattach <PID> threaddump`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236643/discussion-between-mahesh-and-apangin).

Answer (score 1):

The command you should use is:

```
docker exec -i <container_id_or_name> <your_monitoring_command>
```

The command will be executed inside the container, but it will report its output (by `-i`) to the caller console.

Comment: Hello @Antonio, Yes I am able to capture data if I execute ```jstack``` within the container. But I am looking for a solution to do it from an outside container.

Comment: The solution I provided you is out of the container.

Comment: Here is my command ```docker exec -t <container_id_or_name> jstack <PID> > thread_dump.txt```. I passed PID of a process from the host PID namespace and got "No such a process" message inside ```thread_dump.txt``` file. It is working fine if I use PID from the container's PID namespace. Is there any command to get the PID from the container? Currently, I am using ```ps``` inside a container and getting PID.

Comment: Try using `docker ps`.

Comment: Hello Friend, ```docker ps``` is returning a list of running containers.